# Javascript display property not working

Tags: javascript

Here, `team_hover()` is a onmouseover event and `team_hover_bbye()` is a onmouseout event. `team_hover()` is running perfectly but when I remove my mouse from the element `team_hover_bbye()` gets executed but the display property of `gl2` does not changes to none....

I want to change the display property of `gl2` back to none when I remove the mouse.

P.S this is my first post..

```js
function team_hover() {
  var a = document.getElementById("gl1");
  var b = document.getElementById("gl2");
  var myVar = setInterval(opac, 20);
  var i = 0;

  function opac() {
    i = i + 0.1;
    a.style.opacity = 1 - i;
    if (i >= 1) {
      a.style.display = "none";
      b.style.display = "block";
    } else {}
  }
}

function team_hover_bbye() {
  var i = document.getElementById("gl1");
  var j = document.getElementById("gl2");
  i.style.opacity = 1;
  i.style.display = "block";
  j.style.display = "none";
}

team_hover_bbye();
```

```css
#gl1, #gl2 { display: inline-block; width: 2em; height: 2em; margin: 0.5em; }
#gl1 { background: #F00; }
#gl2 { background: #0F0; }
```

```html
<div id="gl1" onmouseover="team_hover()"></div>
<div id="gl2" onmouseover="team_hover()"></div>
```

Comment: Everything else is working fine?

Comment: Can you add working sample in fiddle/plunker?

Comment: You should edit your question and create a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the interval that keeps rolling forever and you're using the wrong events.

Try this:

```js
var myVar;

function team_hover() {
  var a = document.getElementById("gl1");
  var b = document.getElementById("gl2");
  clearInterval(myVar); // Needed here
  myVar = setInterval(opac, 20);
  var i = 0;

  function opac() {
    i = i + 0.1;
    a.style.opacity = 1 - i;
    if (i >= 1) {
      a.style.display = "none";
      b.style.display = "block";

      clearInterval(myVar); // Performance gain
    } else {}
  }
}

function team_hover_bbye() {
  clearInterval(myVar); // Real fix
  var i = document.getElementById("gl1");
  var j = document.getElementById("gl2");
  i.style.opacity = 1;
  i.style.display = "block";
  j.style.display = "none";
}

team_hover_bbye();
```

```css
#gl1, #gl2 { display: inline-block; width: 2em; height: 2em; margin: 0.5em; }
#gl1 { background: #F00; }
#gl2 { background: #0F0; }
```

```html
<div id="gl1" onmouseenter="team_hover()"></div>
<div id="gl2" onmouseout="team_hover_bbye()"></div>
```

It's also worth noticing that what you're trying to archive can be done with CSS.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Had great helo